# Do I need to show the Schengen visa annulment form when applying for the visa next time? Also, how can I explain myself in my benefit?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

My Schengen visa was cancelled (annulled) at the departing airport itself, in Sep 2017.

1. I had connecting flights operated by 2 airlines with a layover of more than 8 hours in Istanbul with neither of the airlines responsible for my accommodation at the layover (apparently it’s mandatory beyond 8hours of layover — learnt it the hard way). This led them to ask me more questions about my travel leading to my itinerary.
2. By mistake, and in the crazy succession of events I did not realize I showed them my old/stale itinerary (idk why I had that in the first place) — it was the exact same dates of travel. However, my stay was a couple days more in Italy than in Switzerland (and my visa was from Swiss embassy, and the new itinerary had equal number of days). And before I could even get a chance to explain, things got escalated in no time and my visa was canceled on the spot.

Later, I got the annulment form from the embassy marked with 3 points (in the lines of conditions not met; unsure if I’d return back)

Now, I have to go to Ireland for a conference in 2 months and then again to Italy for a research visit in Fall (maybe oct through Dec). And this time I will be applying from the US (where I am on a F1 visa and have the visa valid till June 2024)

My questions are:

1. Will I need the official annulment form as a supporting document in my applications (I ask because I have the form in India (I’m Indian) so I will have to get it mailed to me).
2. How best can I explain my situation in the next applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Who cancelled your visa at the airport?

Comment: You should at least explain your situation so that the recipient understands what you are trying to tell. As you ask the question here, a lot of relevant details are missing from your story. First of all, who are the 'them' you are referring to in point 1. It sounds (but I am not sure) as if your visa was cancelled when trying to enter Italy or Switzerland after arriving from India(?) with a transit in Istanbul, but in that case, it does not make sense that the immigration officer was interested in details about your transit in Istanbul, which obviously had worked out as expected.

Comment: The officials at the check-in counter in India (my first departing airport) canceled the visa on behalf of the Swiss Embassy. Essentially, I did not even begin my trip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**.

Your conference is in Ireland. Ireland being the principal destination of your upcoming trip, you'll apply at the Irish consulate in the US (your current and legal country of residence). A list of Irish consulates is found on [this Irish government website](https://dfa.ie/irish-embassy/usa/about-us/team-ireland-in-the-usa/irelands-us-consulates/). Where you live in the US will dictate the consulate to which you apply.

Even if the Irish consulate says they don't want the original annulment letter, they might change their mind during the application process. With two months to go before the Irish conference, time is getting short.

To maximize the chances that you'll have what you need:

- Have a friend or family member in India scan the annulment document and email the scan to you now.
- As a backup if the Irish consulate now (or the Italian consulate later) wants to see the original annulment letter, have your Indian contact copy the annulment letter (always good to have a physical copy as backup). Ask that person to now send the original annulment letter to you via a reputable international courier (FedEx, DHL, UPS, *et al*). The package will be trackable, and should arrive in less than a week.
- Draft the explanation (discussed lower down in this answer)
- Start the application at the Irish consulate. You may find they don't need the original document. If the consulate wants it, or changes their approach mid-process and asks for it, you'll quickly be able to provide it.

**Question 2**.

Visa examiners are interested in relevant facts, not extraneous facts or emotion.

Your explanation should contain the relevant points, and no extraneous or unnecessary material. The explanation should be emotionally neutral, and it should not read as whining or wingeing, seeking special treatment, complaining about what happened, or self-abnegation. The explanation should contain the necessary facts, and be as short as possible.

For instance, in Section 1 of the first part of your question, all the words after "Istanbul" are superfluous and can be omitted. The only relevant points are that you had a long layover in Istanbul, and were questioned about your itinerary. The matters presented in the Section 2 can (and should be) similarly limited and condensed, with emotion and self-abnegation removed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @DavidSupportsMonica.

For Question 2: Would you suggest that I mention about carrying an old itinerary? Or should I just say that the itinerary was not the same as that at the time of visa procurement? Since you said the visa examiners would entertain only relevant facts, I'm wondering if mentioning about the mistake of carrying an old itinerary might seem inconceivable to them?

PS: sorry, I couldn't respond earlier since I posted the question as a guest user initially and the site wouldn't let me comment.

Comment: People make mistakes. Carrying an earlier superseded itinerary was an error, of course, because it allowed you to further err by producing the inaccurate superseded itinerary to the officer. I think that's relevant. I would explain that I inadvertently handed over a earlier draft of my itinerary, whose content was inaccurate because it had been superseded by a new and slightly-different itinerary.

Comment: Alright, I'll draft my response in the suggested manner. Thank you. 

Would you have any other suggestions that I should be careful with when applying for both Ireland and Italian visa?

Comment: The common advice given on this Stack is answer the questions that are asked, answer truthfully, and don't volunteer information that isn't asked for. Your application should be coherent, understandable, and complete; rants and emotion and criticism of yourself or others will not help and should be avoided. Shorter is better than longer. Good luck with your applications!

Comment: Thank you, David!

Comment: Ireland is not in Schengen, so there will need to be two visa applications, one to Ireland and one to Italy. Italy will naturally be more concerned about a former Schengen visa annulment than Ireland, being in Schengen itself.